# Issue in vim-rspec - not mapping the right path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rspec, macvim

The vim-rspec mapping is only getting the right path for one test. Somehow all the other tests are not loading with the right path.

When I do the command inside vim on the file that works, it gives the right command:

`rspec spec/controllers/queue_items_controller_spec.rb`

But for all the other specs, the path comes with the parent folders:

```
rspec /(...)/(...)/(...)/spec/controllers/reviews_controller_spec.rb
```

I have the following on my .vimrc

```
 " vim-rspec mappings
 let g:rspec_runner = "os_x_iterm"
 map <Leader>t :call RunCurrentSpecFile()<CR>
 map <Leader>s :call RunNearestSpec()<CR>
 map <Leader>l :call RunLastSpec()<CR>
 map <Leader>a :call RunAllSpecs()<CR>
```

I am using iTerm2 + Vim + Tmux.

Does any one knows how I fix this mapping issue?

Comment: Do you have `:set autochdir`? In any case, this sounds like an issue with the plugin that you should report to its author, not here.

Comment: I just found where the error is. It is actually an issue when you open the file through NERDTree. I did not find a solution for this specific issue, so for now I am just opening the spec files through CtrlP.

Comment: Alright. Please document your findings in an answer, or delete your question if you think this is too specific to be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I just found where the error is. It is actually an issue when you open the file through NERDTree. I did not find a solution for this specific issue, so for now I am just opening the spec files through CtrlP. – Gustavo Varallo